# porque al crear un proyecto en angular no me crea el appmodule.ts?

Tags: nodejs, angular

tengo la version node js 18.13.0 y angular 17.2.1
estoy trabjando con windows 10 home

Comment: Porque en la documentación oficial te dice que está usando `standalone` y eso, trabaja sin módulos. Acostúmbrate a leer, https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> altamente recomendado. Por cierto, bienvenido/a a SOes :D